# helm-grep-do-git-grep - search only in current dir

Tags: helm-grep

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

If I run command `M-x helm-grep-do-git-grep`  it's search text in current folder and all subfolders. But I need to search text only in current folder.

How I can do this?